# How can I calculate how long ago a boolean record occurred in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have a table `iot` that has some sensor data, one of the columns is booleans as indicators that some event occurred, how can I calculate how long ago the most recent `true` value happened in a column using SQL?

The example data set looks something like the following:

| ts | sensor |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-07T17:12:36.314688Z | true |
| 2021-04-07T17:12:43.995006Z | false |
| 2021-04-07T17:12:47.447316Z | false |
| 2021-04-07T17:12:53.276256Z | true |
| 2021-04-07T17:12:58.723072Z | false |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in SQL, it's possible to use `datediff()` for calculating the difference in time between your timestamp and now.

This query returns two columns:

- the timestamp of the record
- the duration in seconds from the timestamp until now

```sql
select datediff('s', now(), iot.ts) diff, ts 
from iot
```

Example response:

| diff | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 56241 | 2021-04-07T17:12:36.314688Z |
| 56233 | 2021-04-07T17:12:43.995006Z |
| 56230 | 2021-04-07T17:12:47.447316Z |
| 56224 | 2021-04-07T17:12:53.276256Z |
| 56219 | 2021-04-07T17:12:58.723072Z |

If you want to have the latest reading for a value, you can use:

```sql
select datediff('s', now(), iot.ts) diff, ts 
from iot
latest by sensor where sensor
```

This will perform `where` filtering first to return rows where `sensor=true` then on the remaining rows, return the latest record:

| diff | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 56224 | 2021-04-07T17:12:53.276256Z |

For the units of datediff, you can use seconds, minutes, hours, days, months or years. For more info, see the [documentation for datediff](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/date-time#datediff)